# Определяющие признаки CMS Drupal

Tags: drupal, cms

В сети есть много тем о том, как определить ту или иную CMS. Но все способы определения приводят к одному: анализу генерированного уникального кода, который характерен лишь для данной CMS.

**Вопрос.** Каким уникальным кодом (суффиксы, имена папок, пути и пр.) распознается и определяется CMS Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общие принципы, подходящие для многих случаев:

1) Явные признаки в коде (meta generator, комментарии с префиксом и т.д.)

2) Характерные названия классов и id, у друпал:

```
<body class="html front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-main with-navigation with-subnav dir-ltr" >

<body class="front not-logged-in page-front no-sidebars home-page">

<li class="first leaf">
<li class="last leaf">
```

...

3) Пути: где находятся картинки, js, css; как формируются ссылки на разделы (например, для друпала могут встречаться "node/1234")

3a) Друпал:

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings ...
```

4) [robots.txt](http://robots.txt), характерный друпаловский:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# Directories
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /misc/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /profiles/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /themes/
# Files
Disallow: /CHANGELOG.txt
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /INSTALL.mysql.txt
Disallow: /INSTALL.pgsql.txt
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /INSTALL.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /MAINTAINERS.txt
Disallow: /update.php
Disallow: /UPGRADE.txt
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /comment/reply/
Disallow: /filter/tips/
Disallow: /node/add/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /user/register/
Disallow: /user/password/
Disallow: /user/login/
Disallow: /user/logout/
# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /?q=admin/
Disallow: /?q=comment/reply/
Disallow: /?q=filter/tips/
Disallow: /?q=node/add/
Disallow: /?q=search/
Disallow: /?q=user/password/
Disallow: /?q=user/register/
Disallow: /?q=user/login/
Disallow: /?q=user/logout/
```

В общем, смотрим на потроха сайтов и думаем :-)